# How to fix Jenkins error. no such table: users_user

Tags: django, sqlite, jenkins

Not sure where to start.
I just want Jenkins to run tests via `python manage.py test`

In my VirtualEnv build step I run migrations after installing necessary packages. I then try to run `python manage.py test` which cannot complete.

Output:

```
[...]
  Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... OK
  Applying users.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
[...]
```

Part of Traceback (starting @ `test` command):

```
+ python manage.py test
/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/environ/environ.py:628: UserWarning: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/New_Performance_Realm/speedrealm/.env doesn't exist - if you're not configuring your environment separately, create one.
  warnings.warn(
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 421, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: users_user

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 55, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 725, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases(aliases=databases)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 643, in setup_databases
    return _setup_databases(
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 179, in setup_databases
    connection.creation.create_test_db(
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 74, in create_test_db
    call_command(
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 181, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 214, in handle
    self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 353, in sync_apps
    self.stdout.write('    Running deferred SQL...')
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.connection.check_constraints()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 371, in check_constraints
    cursor.execute(
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/1d61c5c6/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 421, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: users_user
Build step 'Virtualenv Builder' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Following the traceback it appears its a sqlite3 error which is what the test db instance is.
I looked at the test db and verified a `users_user` table has been created. Why is Jenkins giving me this error? I also use MySQL but I get a permission denied error.

This all works locally btw, deleteing the db, re-creating, running migrations, and running the test.

Comment: Is `jenkins` your *app_name* ? If it is, then try to run `python manage.py makemigrations jenkins`.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, I found there were multiple errors but seemed hidden. I ran one test at a time and the first test had an actual failure. I can update this when I edit all of the tests, to verify if this is indeed the problem.